# How to prove that $\frac 12+ \frac 13+\dots + \frac 1n < \log n < 1 + \frac 12+ \dots + \frac {1}{n-1} $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analytic-number-theory, riemann-integration

> If $n \in \mathbb N$ and $n \geq 2$,  then we have $\frac 12+ \frac 13+\dots + \frac 1n < \log n < 1 + \frac 12+ \dots + \frac {1}{n-1} $.

My try : Once if we can prove that for all $k \in \mathbb N$ and $k \geq 2$, $\frac 1k < \int_{k-1}^{k} \frac 1t dt < \frac {1}{k-1}$ then we are done.

But I am finding difficulty in proving the inequality $\frac 1k < \int_{k-1}^{k} \frac 1t dt < \frac {1}{k-1}$. Help needed!

Comment: make a little drawing

Comment: Please try to avoid using titles that contain only MathJax in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just need to prove that for any $n\geq 2$ we have:

$$\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \leq \frac{1}{n} \tag{1}$$
then apply induction, but $(1)$ is trivial, since $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence:
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\leq\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}\leq\frac{1}{n}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: How to show 
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \leq \frac{1}{n}$$ for $n\geq 2$.