# Proof that $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} < \ln n < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n - 1}$

Tags: calculus

Please help me to prove this inequality

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} < \ln n < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n - 1}$$

Comment: You seem to have the inequality reversed.  How can the leftmost expression be less than the rightmost?

Comment: @D Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, where did you find this question? What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dedhert.Jr The first comment says that where you have written $a<b<c$, it should instead be $c < b< a$.

Comment: In any case, just compare $\int_{k-1}^k\frac {dx} x$ to either $\frac 1{k - 1}$ or $\frac 1 k$.

Comment: @RRL I disagree with the duplicate marking since the linked question does not directly ask about the same bounds. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1347206/81360) would be more apt

Comment: @D I suspect, however, that you simply forgot the $1$ in front of the sum $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n-1}$, which is a different issue

Comment: @Ben Grosmann... So, was the question wrong?

Comment: @Dedhert If you have copied the question without any mistakes, then yes: the question must be wrong. We would have a better idea of what's going on, however, if you could provide context as I suggest in my first comment.

Comment: Oh, thanks @Ben Grossmann. So, I actually found this question in one of the books, the name of books is Calculus, made by Varberg, Purcell, and Rigdon, Volume 1, Ninth edition. But it translated in Indonesian language.

Comment: @Dedhert.Jr Ok, thanks for explaining. Yes, it seems that there's a typo in the book then. I think that [this is the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1347206/81360) that the author meant to ask.

Comment: Do you have a few questions that it similar to this question above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a simple picture for this,

if we have $g(x) > 0$ but $g'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; g(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  g(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  g(x) \; dx   $$

You need two versions, with $a=2,b=n$
$$ \sum_{j=2}^n \; \frac{1}{j} \; < \; \int_{1}^{n} \;  \frac{1}{x} \; dx = \log n  $$

$a=1 , b= n-1$
$$  \log n = \int_{1}^{n} \;  \frac{1}{x} \; dx  <   \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \; \frac{1}{j}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\lfloor x\rfloor\le x\le\lceil x\rceil\implies \frac1{\lceil x\rceil}\le \frac1x\le \frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}.$$

Integrate in unit intervals and sum.

> $$\frac1n\le\log(n)-\log(n-1)\le\frac1{n-1}$$ which telescopes to $$H_{n}-1\le\log(n)-\log(1)\le H_{n-1}.$$